# Theme has superfish - how to add supersubs?

Tags: jquery, javascript

I'm using a theme that is using Superfish for the navigation menu. The problem is, if the sub item is too long it will drop underneath, i want to keep the individual menu item's text on one line.

Now i've found supersubs for the superfish menu but i don't know how to add it to the theme.

This is in the functions.php file.

```
wp_enqueue_script('superfish', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/superfish.js');
```

and this is in the header.php file.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($){
$(document).ready(function(){
//Drop Down Menu
$('ul.sf-menu').superfish({ 
    delay: 1000,
    animation: {opacity:'show',height:'show'},
    speed: 'normal',
    autoArrows:  true,
    dropShadows: false
    });
});
});
</script>
```

How can i add supersubs to the menu as well to solve the problem i'm having with the sub items.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding this to the themes functions.php?

```
 function add_supersubs() {
    wp_enqueue_script('superfish', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/superfish.js');
    wp_register_script('supersubs', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/supersubs.js','superfish');
    wp_enqueue_script('supersubs');
  }    

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_supersubs'); //
```

this assumes the supersubs.js is in the js folder of the main theme directory.

You'll also need to modify the header js to fit supersubs.

Comment: I would recommend putting the register/enqueue functions for supersubs in the same callback as the enqueue for superfish, just for clarity. Also, it might be useful to make superfish a dependency for supersubs?

Comment: Thanks BandonRandon, but what about the header.php. What do i put in there?

Comment: @Corbula I've never used supersubs but the docs seem to help you out here http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/#examples (see example 5)

Comment: @ChipBennett I agree, just without the callback it's hard to do that :)

Comment: @BandonRandon well, you could always *move* the superfish enqueue *into* the callback you're creating. :)